# Dividing/Multiplying Gaussians

Tags: probability, distributions, normal-distribution

One of the steps in Expectation Propagation based inferencing is to be able to divide out a factor which has a normal form from the current posterior distribution (which is a high dimensional Gaussian). The idea is that the division removes the influence of that factor from the posterior distribution.

So, assume that the posterior is multivariate normal with a n-dimensional mean and a $n$ $\times$ $n$ covariance matrix. Now, my likelihood depends on a subset of this n-dimensional parameters (actually 3. So, displacement along the 3 spatial dimensions and has a variance of $\sigma$). Just to make it clear, the likelihood is defined in terms of the residual as:

$$
L(e) \propto \exp^{-0.5 e \sigma e}
$$

where $e$ is the residual that depends non-linearly on sub-set of posterior parameters $w$ and has a precision given by $\sigma$ ($\sigma$ is a global noise precision). Just to explain, regardless of the fact that the likelihood is normally distributed wrt to the residuals it should still be seen as a function of $w$ for EP to work.

Now, my question is how can I generate such a factor? So, the factor I need to be designed should be a normal distribution that is a function of all of $w$ but depends on only a subset of $w$ (those 3 elements). Also, I need to somehow generate a precision matrix that will be equivalent to the $\sigma$ and more importantly if I divide the posterior distribution by this Gaussian factor, it would be equivalent to removing the influence of this factor from the posterior distribution.

I hope I have managed to explain the problem clearly. Please let me know if I can make it clearer.